# Managing multiple RabbitMQ services on one machine, having the management plugin enabled

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, windows-server-2012

I installed multiple rabbitmq Services on our dev environment and enabled the management plugin and gave them different ports. This works fine, now I installed 3 rabbit MQ nodes on another machine and installed the management plugin. Of course I adjusted the configs and gave the management tools different ports. Unfortunately I can only access the management plugin from rabbitmq 1, 2 and 3 are not working.
I checked and see that some folders are missing in the setup.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ1\db
```

inside of this folder I am missing the plugins folder which I have in the rabbitmq1 setup. I tried to cheat and copy the folders and rename them, but as soon as I start the service it recognizes this and delete the folder.

Re-installing the management plugin does not work, whenever I try to install I get the message that I already have it.

Any idea?

Comment: What errors do you get in the logs? Are you trying to login remotely with the guest:guest user?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. When you create the rabbit-mq and you don't have a config in the `AppData\Roaming/YourRabbitInstance` than there will be no config parameter created in the registry. Meaning your config will never be picked up, whatever details you provide. I have added the config parameter to the registry and the queue immediately started listing on the ports defined in the cfg.

```
-config "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\myrabbit\\myrabbit"
```